# How I can do a loop in a xml file that I get a Attributte value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, loops

Hi I have a xml file and a string from active directory...I want to check the string with the value from the xml file.

**here is xml:** Permissiongroups.xml

```
<Permissiongroup>
  <Permission canonicalname="OU=dbg,OU=de,OU=zzz,DC=company_test,DC=com" display="group" />
  <Permission canonicalname="OU=brv,OU=de,OU=zzz,DC=company_test,DC=com" display="group" />
  <Permission canonicalname="OU=EK,OU=brv,OU=de,OU=zzz,DC=company_test,DC=com" display="group" />
</Permissiongroup>
```

**My C# Code:**

```
string canonicalname = user.canoncialName; //here I get the canonicalname of the search user
```

//for example is here **"CN=Tarasov\, W,OU=PRG,OU=IT,OU=dbg,OU=de,OU=zzz,DC=company,DC=com"**

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Permissiongroups.xml"); // Get XML Path
string group = GetGroup(path, canonicalname); // Get User that match with canonicalname
```

here my method:

```
private string GetGroup(string xml, string canonicalname) 
{
   XDocument document;
   XElement element;

   try
   {
     document = XDocument.Load(xml);

     //check every attribute canonicalname in the xml with the string canonicalname

     //return display value from the element with attributte canonicalname = canonicalname

   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
    return null;
   }
   finally 
   {
    document = null;
    element = null;
   }

 }
```

Now is My Question how I can make a loop in a xml that give me the attribute canoicalname value. That I need for check it with the other string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var permissions = document.Descendants("Permission");

foreach (var p in permissions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Attribute("canonicalname").Value);
}
```

This is just an example how to print those values but I think that you will do the rest because I don't know what this check requirements are.

If you want to find a `Permission` that match your `canonicalname` you can try this code:

```
var searchedPermission = permissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("canonicalname").Value == canonicalname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to XML approach. First find all attributes canonicalname in the xml with the string canonicalname:

```
var q = (from c in doc.Descendants("Permission")
        where string.Equals(c.Attribute("canonicalname").Value, canonicalname)
        select c).ToList();
```

Then display values:

```
foreach (var item in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("canonicalname").Value);
}
```